# ReceiveOneOrMore returns wrong length in Symbian

Tags: c++, symbian

I am doing some socket stuff on Symbian, which works fine so far. However,
I am facing a weird problem when trying to read out the data that has been sent.
Assume the code looks as follows:

```
TSockXfrLength len;

iSocket.RecvOneOrMore( buff, 0, iStatus, len );     
User::WaitForRequest(iStatus);                  
if (iStatus == KErrNone) 
{
   printf(_L("Bytes received 1st try %4d..."), len);
   printf(_L("Bytes Length received 2nd try %4d..."), &len);
}
```

Output in both cases is something with 7450 although I received exactly 145 bytes.
I can check that with a network analyser. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here that
I do not get the proper bytes that have been received?

EDIT:

I am connecting to the socket in the following way:
        TInetAddr serverAddr;
        TUint iPort=445;

```
    TRequestStatus iStatus;
    TSockXfrLength len;

    TInt res = iSocketSrv.Connect();

    res = iSocket.Open(iSocketSrv,KAfInet,KSockStream, KProtocolInetTcp);

    serverAddr.SetPort(iPort);
    serverAddr.SetAddress(INET_ADDR(192,100,81,54));

    iSocket.Connect(serverAddr,iStatus);

    User::WaitForRequest(iStatus);
```

Hope that helps ;)

Thanks

Comment: How are you connecting your socket?

Comment: As requested, I added the code for connecting to the socket

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
printf(_L("Bytes received 1st try %4d..."), len());
```

The `TSockXfrLength` type is actually a typedef of `TPckgBuf<TInt>.` This is the Symbian Descriptor way of storing arbitrary simple data in a 8-bit descriptor. To retrieve the value from the len object you need to use the () operator.

More information about TPckg* classes are available in the symbian developer library.